# VSCode - How to typehint node_modules types in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

If i'm writing JavaScript (not TypeScript) in the VSCode editor, it seems like it isn't able to find the types of many modules.

For example, I'm trying to typehint ExpressContext of ApolloServer (apollo-server-express), it can't find ExpressContext:

[image]

And yet, if I check the parameters of a function that uses ExpressContext, Intellisense can find it there:

[image]

So how do I make it so that I can Cmd+Click on ExpressContext in the @param JSDoc and it brings me to the correct type definition?